# Which self-reference restrictions can be weakened in probabilstic logic?

Tags: pr.probability, lo.logic, mathematical-philosophy

This [work](http://intelligence.org/files/DefinabilityTruthDraft.pdf) suggests that there is some generalization of Truth in terms of probability, which can be definable within the logic itself.

Is where any other thorems on self-reference restrictions, which can be weakened with some consistent probability generalisations?